# Add folder name to beginning of filename - getting multiple renames

Tags: batch-rename

I've used dbenham's excellent [response to the question](https://superuser.com/a/516214/50173) of how to add the folder name to the beginning of a filename in a cmd script.

```
@echo off
pushd "Folder"
for /d %%D in (*) do (
  for %%F in ("%%~D\*") do (
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
      ren "%%F" "%%~nxP_%%~nxF"
    )
  )
)
popd
```

What I'm finding is that seemingly randomly (though it probably isn't) sometimes the script will run through several child folders and rename correctly but then it gets to a folder where it gets stuck in a loop and starts adding the folder name repeatedly to the file inside. I have 90,000 files in 300 folders to rename this weekend. Any chance you can guess the cause?

PS: Is there a maximum number of files that are acceptable in each folder?

Comment: might help to add a reference to the original question you are referring to.

Comment: Maybe you have junction folders somewhere in your target directory. I [had a powershell script](http://superuser.com/questions/528487/list-all-files-and-dirs-without-recursion-with-junctions/528499#528499) to list all non-junction files/folders. Maybe you can tweak it to list only junctions. Otherwise I'll try it :)

Comment: I've opened up powershell (windows 7 pc) which I've never used before.... but I'm getting execution of scripts is disabled on my system.  I can't disable it as my registry key is locked. :(

Comment: If anyone has a simpler solution, I'm quite happy to go through each folder manually.  I've just tried a forfiles solution but this has the same problem.

Comment: nixda, assuming I have junction folders, what would I do about it?