# How to find hard linked folders via programming

Tags: links, mklink, dir

Is it possible to identify if a folder is actually a hard link created by *mklink*?

I want to get folders and subsequent sub-folders. But hard linked folders drops me into a loop.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question because @Dhiwakar is right about "hard linked folders". But in case you only want to avoid loops, [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/528499/50173) could be helpful. Btw. it doesn't matter if a junction point is created via mlink or any third-party tool. They all use the same technique

Comment: thanx a lot, I think the information in the page you introduced solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create hardlinks for folders. There's no such thing. You can create junction points and symbolic links for folders.

These can be identified with the following command

```
junction -s pathname
```

You can find hard links for folders with the following command

```
fsutil hardlink list filename
```

Comment: Dhiwakar Ravikumar,

than you very much, but: 1- I use MKLINK to make hardlinks. 2- I didn't find junction as a internal or external command in my OS (windows 8).

again thank you, and request any one to help me to find junction

Mehrdad Ahankhah

www.irancad.com

Comment: sorry @user4002852. You need SysInternals to run the first command. You can get it from here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx & you need fsutil. You can use any command/tool you like to create a hardlink,junction point,symlinks.It makes no difference.

Comment: Thank you Dhiwakar Ravikumar, I appreciate your great help!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if (The Tick Mark) if you feel this answer helped you or solved your problem. Thanks