# Merging Scripts...Wrong Type of File-Object (Maybe)?

Tags: powershell, recursion

I have a script that I used very frequently to get a list of files and then process them with ffmpeg, the beginning of which read:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "Season *\*" -Include *.mp4, *.mkv, *.m4v, *.avi, *.wmv, *.mpg -recurse
ForEach ($file in $files) {
  $parent = Split-Path $file -parent
  $origFile = $parent+'\'+$file.name
  $shortName = $file.name
....
```

I needed a solution to be able to use it in directories that was more flexible, but avoided the junctions in a directory (the recurse command will travel forever down the junctions). I found an answer here on superuser, [link](https://superuser.com/a/528499/180407). I wrapped my original script in a function and modified the 4th line of the recurse function found on here to call the function and process the files as they were found.

```
function Recurse($path) {
  $fc = new-object -com scripting.filesystemobject
  $folder = $fc.getfolder($path)
  foreach ($i in $folder.files) {if ($i.name -match '.*\.(mp4|mkv|m4v|avi|wmv|mpg)$') {processFile($i)}}
  foreach ($i in $folder.subfolders) {
    $i | select Path        
    if ( (get-item $i.path).Attributes.ToString().Contains("ReparsePoint") -eq $false) {        
        Recurse($i.path)
    }
  }
}

function processFile($file) {
  $parent = Split-Path $file -parent
  $origFile = $parent+'\'+$file.name
  $shortName = $file.name
...
```

But, clearly the way the recurse function operates and generates the list does not create the same type of file-object(?) that the get-childitem does. The operations like "Split-Path $file -parent" now do not work and instead return nothing. Everything I've tested system to indicate that the variable $file is a System._ComObject, which I'm assuming is set in that first command of the recurse functions. Is that not what Get-Childitem returns? How do I get the two functions to work together?

I'm open to modifying either the original script, or the recurse function so that the original capability (such as calling Split-Path) works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System._ComObject, which I'm assuming is set in that first command of the recurse functions. Is that not what Get-Childitem returns?

No. The COM objects returned from the [scripting.filesystemobject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx) are different types of objects then what you get from the [Powershell File system provider](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847764.aspx).  The Powershell provider basically is composed of .NET [System.IO.FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) objects.  While it may seem like they are the same, since they are both dealing with filesystem operations, the two types of objects are not compatible.

Microsoft does provide a document that [suggest conversions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692757.aspx).

In fact your script already uses a method to convert them, in one of your if conditionals.  The bit where you do a `get-item $i.path`.  That code fragment basically converting one type of object to the other.  It has `Get-Item` return a powershell filesystem object, and to do that, you give the Get-Item command the full path of the returned by the scripting.filesystemobject value you have in `$i`.  You should be able to do this same trick in your other places as well.

Comment: Thank you! I had found the get-item command, but I was trying everything except for $i.path to get it to work. I tried strings, $i.name, $i, but not $i.path. That worked perfectly! I didn't write the recurse function, so I wasn't familiar with it's inner workings :)